# postgresql - distinct only on one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, aggregate-functions, distinct-on

I have a table called *eatable*. It has columns such as *type, name*.

*type* column has `fruit, veggie, veggie, fruit, veggie` values
.

*name* column has `apple, brinjal, carrot, banana, cabbage`.values

I want the output as, type column must display only 2 rows and name should display all the values.

It should like below:

[image: eatable]

I have tried the below query, but it isn't I am expected:

```
select distinct on (type) type, name from eatable;
```

Help me out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PostgreSQL's  [Aggregate Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
SELECT type
    ,string_agg(NAME, ',') "name"
FROM eatable
GROUP BY type;
```

Result:

```
type   name  
text   text                 
------ ---------------------- 
fruit  apple,banana           
veggie brinjal,carrot,cabbage
```

*OR*

```
SELECT type
    ,array_agg(name) "name"
FROM eatable
GROUP BY type;
```

Result:

```
type   name  
text   text[]                   
------ ------------------------ 
fruit  {apple,banana}           
veggie {brinjal,carrot,cabbage}
```

---

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/79404/1)